# Am I right about these implications, equalities, and inclusions about sets and Cartesian products?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm reading James R. Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd edition, but I have neither access to any turorial support nor any sort of a solutions manual. So I would from time to time like to keep posting any questions I may have from the book.

Right now, I'm doing the very first exercise set and have this query.

Let $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ be any four arbitrary sets. Then I have arrived at the following statements:

1. $(A \cup B) \setminus (A \cup C) \subset A \cup (B \setminus C)$.
2. $(A \times B) \cup (C \times D) \subset (A \cup C) \times (B \cup D)$.
3. $(A \times B) \cap (C \times D) = (A \cap C) \times (B \cap D)$.
4. $A \times (B \setminus C) =  (A \times B) \setminus (A \times C)$.
5. $(A \setminus B) \times (C \setminus D) = [(A \times C) \setminus (B \times C ) ] \setminus (A \times D)$.
6. $(A \setminus B) \times (C \setminus D) \subset (A \times B) \setminus (C  \times D)$.

In the above statements, by the symbol $\subset$, I mean "is a (proper) subset of".

Now are all the above statements correct? Have I managed to arrive at the correct conclusion in each case?

Comment: Git Gud, instead of correcting my work like this, would you please explicitly say exactly where I've gone wrong?

Comment: He just retagged the question without changing anything else. Click on the "edited" bit above to see the changes.

Comment: Git Gud, are all the statements correct then?